# Is it possible to use a switch statement with expressions as cases?

Tags: php, switch-statement

Using `if` and `elseif`, it is possible to easily perform the comparison below, but for learning purposes I am analyzing if it is possible to have the same functionality using `switch`.

If `$x` receives a positive or negative value, I get the right output, but if `$x` receives `0` (zero), I get the output 'Lower', but the right output should be 'Equal'.

Here is the code:

```
$x = 0;

switch($x)
{
    case ($x < 0):
        echo 'Lower';
        break;

    case ($x == 0):
        echo 'Equal';
        break;

    case ($x > 0):
        echo 'Bigger';
        break;
    default:
        echo 'Not found';
}
```

Is it possible to use a switch statement with expressions as cases?

Comment: There is a "break;" missing after "echo 'Not found';"

Comment: No there isn't, as that's a default.

Comment: @HighKickX, As it is the last option, isn't necessary to put the `break;`

Comment: Why not use `if` and `else if` in this case? It's more readable, and require fewer lines of code.

Comment: @bfavaretto, It's just for learning purposes. You are right, in this specific case `if` and `elseif` would be much more indicated. My main question is to know if is possible to use sentences in each `case` of the `switch`

Comment: @David I agree that it won't change anything

Comment: You can use `switch(true)` and then put expressions in your case statements. (I just realized that GRIGORE-TURBODISEL posted that as an answer long before I got here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are effectively not matching numbers any more, but matching the boolean outcome.

Any positive or negative number casts to boolean `true` and only `0` casts to `false`, so basically for a positive or negative number you are comparing `true` to `($x < 0)` or `($x > 0)` and that gives the outcome you expect.

However, `0` casts to `false` and `(0 == 0)` is `true` so you will never have a match there. And as `0 < 0` is also `false`, your first statement in the switch is matched.

Comment: Since `0 < 0` is `false`, why is first statement matched? The expression evaluates to `false` for both `0 < 0` and `false < 0`.

Comment: @nickb, `$x` being `0`, i understood this: `0 < 0` is `false`? As this expression is `true` it will be matched.

Comment: Very clear explanation, jeroen! Now i understood what is happening, many thanks!

Comment: And when compared to the value passed into switch (`0`), `false == 0`, hence why it matches...

Comment: @nickb, Try to do tests using `switch($x)`, `switch(true)` and `switch(false)`, i think it will clear your doubt.

Answer (score 4):

`switch($x)` replace it with `switch(true)`

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing if the $x is equal to test results, when `$x = 0`, the boolean value of $x is `false`. If it is different from 0, it is `true`. That's why you will always fall to the first test that returns `false`.

Try this instead :

```
$x = 0;

switch($x)
{

case 0:
    echo 'Equal';
    break;

case ($x < 0):
    echo 'Lower';
    break;

case ($x > 0):
    echo 'Bigger';
    break;

default:
    echo 'Not found';

}
```

I also read in the comments that you want to know if it possible to use sentences in each `case` of the `switch`. Yes it is possible :

```
$x = 0;

switch($x)
{

case ($x < 0):
    echo 'Lower';
    break;

case ($x > 0):
    echo 'Bigger';
    break;

case ($x <> 0):
    echo 'Equal';
    break;

default:
    echo 'Not found';

}
```

`($x <> 0)` will return false when `$x = 0` and it will echo "Equal"

Comment: @grigore-turbodisel solution is much more simple, but I found it funny to stick with the switch($x)